# Де правильно ставити прислівник

Tags: прислівники

Як правильно казати *не буду ніколи* чи *ніколи не буду*?

> Не буду *ніколи* цього робити.
>   *Ніколи* не буду цього робити.
>   Не буду цього робити *ніколи*.

або інакше, але тут я зміг змайструвати лише два варіанти:

> Не робитиму цього *ніколи*.
>   *Ніколи* не робитиму цього.

Чи є значеннєва різниця?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всі варіанти правильні, українська мова доволі невибаглива щодо порядку слів. Хоча вживаність різних варіантів може відрізнятися: якісь є найтиповішими, їх щодня можна почути у побутових розмовах, а інші — лише у якійсь поетиці чи при передачі якоїсь особливої конотації.

Різниця в конотації, на мою думку, є, але її важко сформулювати. Мені здається, що люди тяжіють до перенесення ключових слів, що задають напрямок всієї думки, ближче до початку речення. Наприклад:

> — Я зламав машину.
>   *(«…А ще олівець, вимикач світла і гудзика на куртці». Першочерговою інформацією тут є «зламав», а далі може йти перелік того, чого зламав — як важливих речей, так і дрібних або середнього ступеню важливості.)*
>
> — Я машину зламав.
>   *(Найімовірніше це читається так: «Я машину(!) зламав» (або навіть так: «Машину», з великої літери). Мовець в першу чергу акцентує увагу на тому, що́ він зламав, маючи на увазі, що ця річ була дуже важливою для нього. Можливо, єдиним джерелом заробітку чи, приміром, позиченою власністю дуже небезпечних людей.)*

Є й інші випадки, коли слова з типового порядку переносять на початок. Наприклад, підганяючи слова під певні конструкції («*А* <…> *Х*, а *Б* — *не-Х*» — «добре я відпочити на тому курорті все одно не зможу, а витрачати такі гроші за посередній відпочинок не бачу сенсу»).

Хоча найбільшу роль все-таки грає інтонація, а не порядок слів, але певні порядки слів, на мою думку, є типовішими для певних інтонувань (а от просто змінювати порядок слів, не вкладаючи особливої конотації і коли цього не вимагає форма, наприклад віршована, на мою думку, є менш типовим).

А чому змогли змайструвати лише два варіанти? Чим «не робитиму ніколи цього» не варіант? Те, що його рідше вживають, не означає, що він неправильний — він теж може бути вжитий у певних випадках.

<sub>P.S.: Формально українська мова відноситься до [SVO-мов (тобто з порядком subject–verb–object — підмет–дієслово–додаток)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object). Де в цьому порядку місце обставини (а саме цю роль найчастіше виконують прислівники) мені незрозуміло. Але на практиці, як на мене, це і не має значення, бо навіть для підмета–присудка–додатка порядок слів варіюється.</sub>

Comment: Гарно й доступно виклали, @Sasha! Оформлювати додаткову відповідь немає сенсу, але кому цікаво, можна ще додатково почитати: 1) [стисло](http://www.subject.com.ua/ukrmova/zno/246.html), 2) [докладніше і зокрема про обставини](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/sintaksis_i_punktuacija/porjadok_sliv_u_rechenni/7-1-0-189), 3) [акцент на інверсії - непрямому порядку слів](http://www.ukrlit.net/info/criticism/inversion.html).

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, о, то це дуже добре. У відповіді — те, що я сам колись придумував (у джерела навіть і не дивився, бо не думав, що хтось буде розписувати цю тема). А за Вашими посиланнями — це вже що (мабуть) професійні мовознавці із цього приводу пишуть.

Comment: Виходить ([звідси](http://www.ukrlit.net/info/criticism/inversion.html)), що прямий порядок — це «я ніколи не робитиму цього» (прислівникова обставина перед словом, до якого вона відноситься). Але ми в українській мові настільки звикли гратися порядком, що я до цього моменту навіть і не знав, який саме порядок вважається прямим.

Comment: Все-таки я б зробив з Вашого коментаря окрему відповідь. Бо там є інформація, якій у моїй відповіді однозначно бракує — який саме порядок вважається прямим. (Хоч, може, можна додати і в цю, але я поки не знаю, як.)

Comment: Не заперечую, якщо доповните свою :)